# Does Azure support the right version of PHP to run Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to install Laravel 5.5 on Microsoft Azure. I am using (trying) free App service. The `phpinfo()` function return PHP Version 5.6.31. I know that Laravel requires PHP 7+.

Any idea how to resolve that? Is it possible to change PHP version - free subscription or it has to be paid subscription?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/announcing-support-for-php-7-0-in-azure-app-service-and-notice-of-php-5-4-retirement/

Comment: I am not sure how I even missed it. Thank you @Devon and LorenzoBerti.

Comment: @virrion: in general there is no need to add commentary about edits unless they are misrepresent your intended meaning or make the question harder to read (and in such cases you can roll back or liaise with the editor). In this case the edit seemed good, albeit rather minor - long "em" dashes can appear within sentences to indicate a pause, but not between sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how to resolve that? Is it possible to change PHP version

You could change PHP version easily on Azure Portal.

[image]

You also could use Azure Cli 2.0 to change it.

```
az webapp config set --php-version 7.1 -g shuiapp -n shuiphp
```